# Table with 100% width will not float side-by-side

Tags: css, css-tables

I created 2 tables and I want to position them side-by-side (horizontally). However they always align themselves vertically. I tried `float: left;` but it didn't change a thing.

```
table {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you need to add your code here so we can help you.

Comment: Could you add the actual code/styling you're currently using?

Comment: `float: left;` is being made ineffective by `width: 100%`. If the table is 100% wide there is no room next to it for the next table to float into position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
display:inline-block;
```

probably will help. And `width:100%;` sets your table width to window width, remove it.

Comment: The other thing that didn't get conveyed to the OP is that the original css had `#table` which could mean that they were using duplicate `id` values.